# How can I use a variable for `didSet` property from outside of of the method

Tags: swift

How can I use a variable for `didSet` property from outside of of the method

This work

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    var myString = "sadf" {
        didSet{
            print("myString did change from "+oldValue+" to "+myString)
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to do this

```
//add var outside of method
var myString:String!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //call variable inside of method
    myString = "sadf" {
        didSet{
             print("myString did change from "+oldValue+" to "+myString)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "want to do this" makes no sense to me. Please explain what you want to happen. If you just want to print something in `viewWillAppear`, then call `print`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to monitor changes of the variable in `viewWillAppear` from other `funcs`. lets say `func1` changed the `var` I want to know that in `func2` only way for me to know this is if `var` is outside not inside the `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define didSet for the property outside of the method. This should work:

```
var myString:String = "oldString" {
    didSet(oldValue) {
        print("myString did change from "+oldValue+" to "+myString)
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myString = "sadf"
    myString = "secondCall"
}
```

The output will be look like this:

```
myString did change from  to sadf
myString did change from sadf to secondCall
```

For more information you should read the chapter about property observers in the apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the whole `didSet` structure to accompany `myString` defined as a global, as you have it. No law says that `didSet` applies only to a property; it can apply to a global variable or even (though who knows why you'd do this) to a local variable! This is perfectly legal:

```
var myString : String! {
    didSet {
        print("myString changed")
    }
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    myString = "asdf"
}
```

Comment: @Hamish If you know what the OP is saying you're doing better than I am.

Comment: @matt your answer was correct, that is exactly what I was trying to achieve.  there was another user who provide the same answer before you. Thank you

Comment: @pprevalon No problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, declare another `lazy var` to hold the old/new value whichever you want and assign that in your `viewWillAppear` method like below:

```
lazy var changedString = String()
var myString = "sadf" {
    didSet {
        print("myString did change from "+oldValue+" to "+myString)
        changedString = myString
    }
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myString = "this got changed"
}
```